# Load field 1 and print at the END{} equivalent awk in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, awk, foreach, equivalent

I have the following AWK script that counts occurences of elements in field 1 and when finishes to read entire file, prints each element and the times of repetitions.

```
awk '{a[$1]++} END{ for(i in a){print i"-->"a[i]} }' file
```

I'm very new with perl and I don't know how would be the equivalent. What I have so far is below, but it has incorrect syntax. Thanks in advance.

```
perl -lane '$a{$F[1]}++ END{foreach $a {print $a} }' file
```

**____________________________________UPDATE**
**______________________________________**

Hi, thanks both for your answers. The real input file has 34 million lines and the execution time is 3 or more times faster between awk and Perl. Is awk faster than perl?

```
awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(i in a){print i"-->"a[i]}}' file #--> 2:45 aprox
perl -lane '$a{$F[0]}++;END{foreach my $k (keys %a){ print "$k --> $a{$k}" } }' file #--> 7 min aprox
perl -lanE'$a{$F[0]}++; END { say "$_ => $a{$_}" for keys %a }' file # -->9 min aprox
```

Comment: Alternative to an `END` block in a Perl one-liner: the [eskimo greeting operator](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod#Eskimo-greeting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, Ger, one more time :-) 
I upgraded my Perl to the latest version available to me and made a file like what you described (34.5 million lines each having a 16 digit integer in the 1st and only column):

```
schumack@linux2 52> wc -l listbig
34521909 listbig

schumack@linux2 53> head -3 listbig
1111111111111111
3333333333333333
4444444444444444
```

I then ran a specialized Perl line (works for this file but is not the same as the awk line). As before I timed the runs using /usr/bin/time:

```
schumack@linux2 54> /usr/bin/time -f '%E %P' /usr/local/bin/perl -lne 'chomp; $a{$_}++; END{foreach $i (keys %a){print "$i-->$a{$i}"}}' listbig
5555555555555555-->4547796
1111111111111111-->9715747
9999999999999999-->826872
3333333333333333-->9922465
1212121212121212-->826872
4444444444444444-->5374669
2222222222222222-->1653744
8888888888888888-->826872
7777777777777777-->826872
0:12.20 99%

schumack@linux2 55> /usr/bin/time -f '%E %P' awk '{a[$1]++} END{ for(i in a){print i"-->"a[i]} }' listbig
1111111111111111-->9715747
2222222222222222-->1653744
3333333333333333-->9922465
4444444444444444-->5374669
5555555555555555-->4547796
1212121212121212-->826872
7777777777777777-->826872
8888888888888888-->826872
9999999999999999-->826872
0:12.61 99%
```

Both perl and awk ran very fast on the 34.5 million line file and were within a half second of each other.
Curious as what type of machine / OS / Perl version you are currently using. I tested on an ASUS laptop that is about 4 years old, has Intel I7. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and Perl v5.26.1

Anyways, thanks for the reason to play around with Perl!

Have fun,
Ken

Comment: Excellent Ken :) Many thanks for your extra help and tests. With your Perl script I get 14.44 seconds and with awk 14.19 seconds in a Dell machine using  Cygwin and Ubuntu built-in feature on Windows 10, Core I7, 8 gb ram. But it takes 2 min in awk and more than 7 with Perl in the original machine I tested that is Cygwin on Windows 7, Hp core i7, 16 gb ram hehehe

Answer (score 1):

Equivalent to your `awk` line

```
perl -lanE'$a{$F[0]}++; END { say "$_ => $a{$_}" for keys %a }' file
```

By `-a` the line is broken into fields in `@F` so you want `$F[0]` as a key in a hash `%a` with the value of the counter handled by `++`. The hash is iterated over keys and printed in the `END` block.

However, the efficiency comparison comes up. One way to improve this is to not fetch all fields on the line, done with `-a`, since only the first one is needed.  Between two ways that come to mind

```
perl -nE'$a{(/(\S+)/)[0]}++; END { ... }'
```

and

```
perl -nE'$a{(split " ", $_, 2)[0]}++; END { ... }'
```

the `split` is significantly faster with its `3.63s` vs `4.41s` for regex,  on a 8M-line file.

This is still behind `1.99s` for your `awk` line.  So it seems that awk *is* faster for this task.

---

Summary of my timings for an 8-million line file (average of a few runs)

```
awk  (question)  1.99s
perl (split)     3.63s
perl (regex)     4.41s
perl (like awk)  5.61s
```

These timings vary over runs by a few tens of miliseconds (a few 0.01s).

Comment: Thank for  your help. Please see my update. I want to know is there is a way to speed up perl script.

Comment: @GerCas Updated.  I'll look into it more and will update if I find improvements

Answer (score 1):

Input file would obviously make a difference, but Perl 5.22.1 was slightly faster than Awk 4.1.3 below on my 33.5 million line test file (12.23 vs 12.52 seconds).

```
schumack@daddyo2 10-02T18:25:17 54> wc -l listbig
33521910 listbig

schumack@daddyo2 10-02T18:25:58 55> /usr/bin/time -f '%E %P' awk '{a[$1]++} END{ for(i in a){print i"-->"a[i]} }' listbig
1-->9434310
2-->1605840
3-->9635040
4-->5218980
5-->4416060
7-->802920
8-->802920
9-->802920
12-->802920
0:12.52 99%

schumack@daddyo2 10-02T18:26:17 56> /usr/bin/time -f '%E %P' perl -lne '$_=~s/^(\S+) .*/$1/; $a{$_}++; END{foreach $i (keys %a){print "$i-->$a{$i}"}}' listbig 
1-->9434310
5-->4416060
2-->1605840
3-->9635040
12-->802920
8-->802920
9-->802920
4-->5218980
7-->802920
0:12.23 99%
```

Comment: Hi Ken. My input file has one column of 34.5 million lines with values of 16 digits each one. Maybe that is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

This destructive method is the fastest I came up with:

```
perl -lne '$_=~s/\s.*//; $a{$_}++; END{foreach $i (keys %a){print "$i-->$a{$i}"}}' file
```

However, it still is not quite as fast as awk.

Comment: Hi Ken, more than 7 minutes with this perl version, awk 1:37 min. It seems awk is faster. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I guess the file you are reading makes quite a difference! When I tested, the Perl line was only slightly (seconds) slower than Awk.

Answer (score -1):

You can go through [`a2p`](http://perldoc.perl.org/a2p.html)

```
$ cat file
1
1
2
3
3
3

$ perl -lane '$a{$F[0]}++;END{foreach my $k (keys %a){ print "$k --> $a{$k}" } }' file
1 --> 2
2 --> 1
3 --> 3

$ awk '{a[$1]++} END{ for(i in a){print i" --> "a[i]} }' file
1 --> 2
2 --> 1
3 --> 3
```

Comment: Thank for  your help. Please see my update. I want to know is there is a way to speed up perl script.

Comment: @GerCas can't you use awk, in your environment ? these are hashes, I really can't compare perl and awk at my end, if you ask me, I prefer GNU awk most of the time

Comment: Hi Akshay, sometimes awk is not an option, so trying to look for an option. Actually I know that awk is very fast :).

Comment: I think, @EdMorton probably have better idea than anyone here, why awk is faster compare to perl, I am not sure, I guess perl could be spending more time in splitting field `(-a)`, there is an interesting post which I found on search,  see [here](https://libertysys.com.au/2011/03/an-interesting-performance-difference-between-perl-and-awk/)

Comment: Many thanks Akshay for the solution provided and link shared.